# Angularfire2 push() not working on ionic app

Tags: ionic2, angularfire2

This is a code from  my ionic app , iam trying to add a user to a firebase database node, this works on chrome without any issue, but not on device, i added alert inside promise push.then(), and for error, both not fired,

```
import {
    AngularFire,
    FirebaseListObservable,
   } from 'angularfire2';

        export class LoginPage {
         users: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

         user:any{
           email: string,
           first: string,
           last: string,
           password: string
        }
         constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
            this.users = this.af.database.list('/data/users');
        }

        signUp(cred) {
         this.users.push(this.user).then(() => {
         console.log('done')
        })
        }
```

nothing happens when signUp() is called when running on device , but works well on chrome,

Comment: Use [Chrome remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) to see what is happening. Also, where are you initializing `this.user`?

Comment: As mentioned above, what is `this.user`? And what does it contain? Be aware that if it has any properties that are `undefined` the `push` will fail. And you don't have a `catch`, so any errors would be unhandled. Are any errors reported via the console (or the debug log)?

Comment: @Und3rTow, promise not returning resolve, reject

Comment: The actual content of the object you are attempting to `push` is what's needed. You should verify (via the console or the debug log) that *all* of the object's properties have valid value and none are `undefined`. Also, any errors are important and should be included in the question. Be aware, too, that if `push` is called with an `undefined` argument, it simply returns the push key (the keys are generated on the client) and does nothing else. Depending upon the data, what you are seeing could be the expected behaviour.

Comment: im doing delete this.user.$key , before push, i have that $key as user property, i used to update the item, but it shows error when pushing with $key, so i just removing before push

Comment: same code working on chrome, but not on device, thats the problem